# Angular 6 - pulling data from DB periodically

Tags: database, angular

how to hit the db continuously  to get the updated values in DB in an Angular 6 application.
if rxjs timer needs to be used, how to use it effectively to serve my requirement.

Comment: You can call an api that reads a db, but calling the db itself is not what angular does and neither should do. Unless you mean browsers' index db

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/http-polling.html blog may help you to understand how to make http request at a particular time interval

Answer (score 3):

you can use interval in angular6 using rxjs.

`import { interval } from 'rxjs';`

and use the method -

```
interval(5000)
.switchMap(() => this.youApiService.anyMethod())
.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple periodic call to backend API, just call the `makePeriodicReq` method once (in `ngOnInit` for example):

```
import { Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

subscription: Subscription;

makePeriodicReq() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.myService.getFromApi())
    )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.debug('resp', resp);
      });
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Note that the `getFromApi` method returns an observable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can poll at an interval of 2 seconds:

```
 Observable.interval(2000).startWith
          (this.getCompanyDetails(name))
            .subscribe(res => { 
               // do whatever you want here with the response
   });
```

getCompanyDetails is making http call.

Answer (score 0):

```
interval(5000).
pipe(switchMap(() => this.myService.getFromApi()))
.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the difference between your code and the already present solutions are and why you think your solution is better.